# Logitech GHub Lua script Toggle to spam keys

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Hello so im trying to make a script in which i press a mouse button and it starts repeating keys until i press the button again.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then 
 repeat
    PressKey("3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0")
    Sleep(100)
    ReleaseKey("3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0")
 until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4) 
end
end
```

i cant seem to get it working with toggle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have problems trying to keep pressed 8 keys simultaneously.
Windows allows maximum 6 keys to be down at the same time.

```
local btn4

local function is_btn4_pressed_again()
   Sleep(10)
   local btn4_current_state = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
   local answer = not btn4 and btn4_current_state
   btn4 = btn4_current_state
   return answer
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then 
      btn4 = not btn4
      if btn4 then
         repeat
            PressKey("3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0")
            Sleep(100)
            ReleaseKey("3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0")
         until is_btn4_pressed_again() 
      end
   end
end
```